# Printing Hexadecimal fraction number on intel8086

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-16, fractions, emu8086

I want to be able to print a hexadecimal number as a fraction. Lets say .D

```
;This macro registers AH,AL
READ MACRO       
MOV AH,8     
INT 21H
ENDM

;This macro registers AH,DL
PRINT MACRO CHAR
PUSH AX
PUSH DX
MOV DL,CHAR
MOV AH,2
INT 21H
POP DX
POP AX         
ENDM
.main:
READ ;This is Actually .D
xor ah,ah ; clear it
; some code to translate ascii to hex    

; Needed code goes here
```

as you can can see I read the hex character and i want to print it as a fraction.
For Example .D is printed as .8125

I don't understand how to convert it and print it. I am working with intel 8086 assembly only. I understand that this is actually what floating point numbers do in c but i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: So you want to print `x / 16` as a decimal fraction, where `x` is a 4-bit integer (i.e. one hex digit in the 1/16th's place of a hexadecimal fraction).  i.e. `0xd/0x10 = 0x0.D = 0.8125`.  If you google for `hexadecimal fraction`, you'll get some hits, many about converting to/from decimal fractions.  Maybe throw in some other search terms like "integer", because many of the hits use floating point, and floating-point to decimal-fraction is possible (with x87) but slow.

Comment: You don't need to use floating-point; what you're doing is effectively a fixed-point representation (where a fixed number of bits are the fractional part, and the rest are the integer part).  In your case, you have 4 fractional bits and no integer bits.  Fixed-point numbers are normally stored in binary, not decimal, so **what you need is a plain old fixed-point to string conversion**.  See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/109219/50567 for a C implementation using simple integer operations (e.g. multiply by 10 so the integer part is the next decimal digit)

Comment: If you are about only single hexa digit fraction, then you can even have table of 16 strings to display correct fraction for each hexa digit.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes you pointed me to the answear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was really simple when I understood the fixed-point to string conversion. Basically you have translate every bit below zero to their value. Since I only had 4 bits the algorithm was simple:

```
//cl has the bits lets say 0000 1111 = 0F
mov ax,0
rol cl,5     // I only care for the 4 bit. 
             // So i shift 4 times => 1111 0000 and then a 5th
jnc next1    // If carry has not set then skip this bit
add ax,5000  // 1st bit worths 5000 or 1/2 * 10000 to make it an integer
next1:
rol cl,1     // Rotate for the next bit
jnc next2
add ax,2500  // 2st bit worths 2500 or 1/4 * 10000 to make it an integer
next2:
rol cl,1     // Rotate for the next bit
jnc next3
add ax,1250  // 3st bit worths 1250 or 1/8 * 10000 to make it an integer
next3:
rol cl,1     // Rotate for the next bit
jnc next4
add ax,625  // 4th bit worths 625 or 1/16 * 10000 to make it an integer
next4:
```

Now the al register has the result. If we had more bits below zero then we would continue the process. The idea is that every bit worth half what the previous one was. This code isn't optimal but it does the work me.

Comment: `add al,5000` doesn't make much sense.  `al` is an 8-bit register, but `5000` is greater than 255.  Your assembler should warn about truncating the constant.  Are you sure you copied your code correctly?  Maybe you meant to use AX?

Comment: Why do you use `add al,1250` for the last bit when the comment states it's worth 625?

Comment: sorry @SepRoland typo

Comment: @PeterCordes correct this is also a typo for me to fix

Comment: Since the order in which you process the 4 bits is of no importance, you could just as easily start at bit 0 (625) and stop at bit 3 (5000). This would avoid the `rol cl,5` which normally can not be available in a program that calls itself a 8086 emulator!

Comment: @SepRoland you are correct but it makes small difference. This was the initial way I implemented it and you can easily do five single left shift(this is the way the emu8086 did it). You can as easily do right shift but as i said it makes small difference

Comment: My comment was made to address what you said in the original question: "I am working with intel 8086 assembly only." On the 8086 processor it is simply impossible to shift/rotate by any immediate count. The emu8086 program allows it, but it is a bad habbit to use it. That emulator has many more errors and I don't think you would like to follow those too.

Comment: BTW, you can rotate by 1, but the machine encoding is implicit, not as an immediate.  (i.e. a special opcode for `rcl`-by-1, separate from the `rcl`-by-immediate opcode introduced by 186 or 286 (I forget which))

Comment: Anyway, I'd *highly* recommend that you always copy/paste from code you actually tested.  If you'd done that instead of whatever the heck you did, you couldn't have introduced a typo.